# MySQL Taking MAX() of a COUNT(), getting wrong aggregated value

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am having a complex query I will try to simplify here in order to demonstrate my problem.

Besically, for a scheduling application, I am trying to count the number of records (spots) which occur at the same time (in 15 minute intervals), so I group on that. Every block of 15 minutes has a certain calculated column value (age_value) associated with it. For example:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+
| date       | start | spots | age_value |
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 2013-08-05 |   950 |    15 |   1060701 |
| 2013-08-05 |   975 |    15 |   1060701 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1000 |    15 |   1060701 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1025 |    15 |   1060701 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1050 |    14 |   1060700 |
..........................................
| 2013-08-05 |  1275 |    14 |   1060700 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1300 |    12 |   1050600 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1325 |    12 |   1050600 |
..........................................
| 2013-08-05 |  1700 |    12 |   1050600 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1725 |    12 |   1050600 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1750 |    12 |   1050600 |
| 2013-08-05 |  1775 |    12 |   1050600 |
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Now, this is a subquery. Around it I have another query to take the MAX of the number of spots. I.e. What is the MAX number of spots that are taken up during a certain time period (in this case 9:30 - 18:00).

**Now the important part where it goes wrong:** I want to get the age_value of the record which has the highest value for spots. In this case 1060701. The problem however, seems that it will ALWAYS return the age_value for the FIRST row in the subquery. In the example case this is correct, since the first row is also the one with the highest number of spots. But this is not always the case!

What is the best way to do this? It feels kind of dirty to ORDER BY the subquery on spots DESC, which puts the row with the highest spots always on top.

My (simplified) query:

```
SELECT subq.date, MAX(subq.spots) AS max_spots, age_value
FROM (
    SELECT  di.date, 
            ts.start,
            COUNT(*) AS spots,
            SUM(POW(10, ...)) AS age_value
    FROM date_intervals di
        JOIN occupancy_caches oc ON oc.date = di.date
        JOIN time_slices ts ON ts.start < oc.end AND ts.start >= oc.start
    AND ts.start BETWEEN 950 AND 1775
    GROUP BY ts.start, di.date
) subq
GROUP BY subq.date
```

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a MySQL extension which the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) explicitly warns against using.  You should be sure that all the columns in the `select` for an aggregation query are either arguments to aggregation functions or in the `group by` clause -- unless you are really, really sure about what you are doing.

In your case, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick to get what you want:

```
SELECT subq.date, MAX(subq.spots) AS max_spots,
       substring_index(group_concat(age_value order by subq.spots desc), ',', 1) as age_value
FROM (SELECT  di.date, ts.start, COUNT(*) AS spots, SUM(POW(10, ...)) AS age_value
      FROM date_intervals di JOIN
           occupancy_caches oc
           ON oc.date = di.date JOIN
           time_slices ts
           ON ts.start < oc.end AND ts.start >= oc.start AND ts.start BETWEEN 950 AND 1775
      GROUP BY ts.start, di.date
     ) subq
GROUP BY subq.date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Is there any reason to use your solution over an ORDER BY in the sub query from a maintainability and/or performance point of view?

Comment: I still don't see this as an "extension". Returning incorrect results is more of a shortcoming to me - if not a bug (but that might just be me)

Comment: @ChrisDekker . . . The `order by` method uses a feature of MySQL that is explicitly documented to return "indeterminate" results for column values.  I would consider relying on behavior that is documented not to work as being unsafe.